# How to select every second occurrence using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing jquery code which would remove every second occurrence of character " | " in the code.

Having troubles with writing regular expression for it.

How to specify every second occurrence of " | " using regular expressions?

Comment: does `" | "` include the blanks or are you only interested in the pipe?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to match 2 pipes, and replace the second one:

```
theString.replace(/\|([^|]*)\|/g, '|$1');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CAvT4/

Comment: Or even `theString.replace(/(\|[^|]*)\|/g, '$1');`.

Comment: @MRAB - Absolutely right. Although, by rote, I always try to minimize the amount of characters captured.

Answer (score 1):

You have to match 2 pipes to do something with (here: remove) every second one.

```
string.replace(/(\|.*?)\|/g, "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
(?<=.*\|.*)\|
```

With the empty string

This will transform

```
test  | test  ||  test  |  test  || 
test  |||
```

to

```
test  | test    test    test   
test  |
```

I first interpreted your question as to collapse multiple occurrences of | to 1 which this regex would solve

Replace

```
\|{2,}
```

With

```
|
```

What language are you using?

Comment: The OP is using Javascript, which doesn't support lookbehind.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is this mentioned? Ic that Bergi added the tag as well

Comment: The OP wrote of "jQuery". I found that only when Joseph mentioned he would know that it's js :-)