# Use regex to find and replace every second backtick in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a script that will replace every SECOND backtick with a backtick and semi colon. See below for expected behavior:

```
"`Here is my string`"
```

Needs to become:

```
"`Here is my string`;"
```

I have found a few helpful answers on stack, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589667/match-at-every-second-occurrence), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404172/how-to-select-every-second-occurrence-using-regular-expression) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/959478/replace-every-nth-instance-of-a-character-with-a-new-line-in-notepad/959481) but when I try the replacement on [this solution](https://regex101.com./r/0VLWZo/3/) it selects all occurrences, rather than every second occurrence. And on [this solution](https://regex101.com./r/03xGju/2/) it selects every FIRST occurrence instead of every second one.

As of now I have tried...

```
str.replace(/\`.*?\`*/g, '`;')
```

...as well as...

```
str.replace('\w*\`\b/gm, '`;')
```

Both have gotten me close but I can't seem to just get every SECOND backtick by itself.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here? It looks like you're trying to parse and modify JavaScript code, in which case regex really isn't the most appropriate tool.

Comment: This feels like an XY problem, as what @jonrsharpe described. What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am experimenting with automatic semi colon insertion and didn't want to insert a semi colon after every single backtick because then you would change the value of the string itself. Can you elaborate on a better tool than regex for this? I am not married to regex it's just what I've been using thus far.

Comment: Look into AST parsing tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace every second backtick, you might use a capturing group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

In the replacement you could use `$1`;`

```
(`[^`]*)`
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group

  - `` `[^`]* `` Match a backtick, match 0+ times any char except a backtick using a negated character class
- `` )` `` Close group 1 and match a backtick

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nvFXWe/1)

```js
const regex = /(`[^`]*)`/g;
const str = `\`Here is my string\` this is another test \`Here is my string\``;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1\`;`);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Finding the second backtick is easy, but finding *every* second backtick is harder. I think this should work:

```js
"`Here is my string` and `another` and `another`".replace(/`.*?(`.*?`)*?`/g, '$&;');
// -> "`Here is my string`; and `another`; and `another`;"
```

Let's dig into what that regex means.

- it finds 1st backtick, followed by anything. Note the `?` in `.*?`: this makes the match lazy, so that finds the shortest match, not the longest.
- it then finds an even number (0, 2, 4) of following backticks (1 + even = odd number of backticks in total), again separated by anything lazily (`.*?`).
- it then finds a final backtick
- it replaces that in the string with `$&` (= everything was matched) then adds the semicolon.
- The `g` flag at the end then makes it global, so we replace every available match, not just the first one.

Depending on your input you might want to make this more rigorous, it's just a proof of concept. For potentially large inputs especially you may need to watch out for [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with regular expressions including multiple `.*` sections like this.

Comment: When I try it [like this](https://regex101.com./r/0VLWZo/4) it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry @M.C. - I've been tweaking and shortening it, and it was briefly a version that didn't work. Should be all good now!

Comment: I think that does work @CodeManiac - I get one semicolon, after the last backtick. I've updated this a couple of times though, I suspect that didn't work in a previous version.

Comment: @CodeManiac your example is still using an old version, that works now it you try the current regex in the answer. My comment about one semicolon was about the example you posted within your comment, which is different to the one you now link to. In that example, the new regex would correctly add 4 semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
(`[^`]*)`
```

[image]

````js
let str = "`Here is my string` some more string with ``` some more ``` and` and `"

let final = str.replace(/(`[^`]*)`/g,'$1`;')

console.log(final)
````

Comment: You posted exactly the same answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird there was no same answer when i started typing,

Comment: @Thefourthbird posted the same answer just before you so I chose that one but I really appreciate the answer!

Comment: @M.C. glad to hear that, always happy to help :) yeah he beat me with his speed so he deserve reward for that :)

Answer (score 1):

I will share the trick i spotted, then was learning regex. To match everything between two specific char, use this construction:

```
# -- character, that enclosing some content

#[^#]*#
```

In your case, i believe, you want to use [this approach](https://regex101.com/r/3yZTwk/1):

```
`[^`]+(`)
     ^
     use * here, if you want match case, then two backticks do not 
     contain anything
```

Here you match *every* second backtick into first group. After that you can substitute this group to `;

Comment: This appears to select everything in the string, rather than just the second backtick.

Comment: The `+` in you regex matches one or more character... To match `\`\``, use `*` instead...

Comment: @M.C. Yes, $0, or zero-group contais everything regex matched. But i have another groups -- $1, or first. It matches only second backtick.

Answer (score 0):

This expression might simply do that:

```js
const regex = /(.*`.*`)/gm;
const str = `\`Here is my string\``;
const subst = `$1;`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/g5WuJO/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/g5WuJO/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: This only replaces the second backtick, not _every_ second backtick.