# Regex to match react styled-components

Tags: regex

I have a bunch of files with distributed styled components that look like these:

```
const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`
```

The idea is to run a regex pattern to match these and then do the needful optimizations.
I have tried constructing a regex pattern for this and I've come up with:
`` (const)\s*(\S+)\s..(styled)(.*?)\`(\n.*)(\`)? ``

However, this isn't quite working and only captures until the first line after line-break and does not extend until the last `` "`" ``.

Appreciate all the help from regex superheroes out there!

Comment: Try ``"(?m)^const\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*styled\.(\w+)`([\w\W]*?)`"``, see https://regex101.com/r/g1GpyO/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added matches backtick after the your regular expression

```
(?m)((const)\s*(\S+)\s..(styled).(.*?)`([^`]*)`)
```

Group 1: Complete styled const data
Group 2: const
Group 3: Name of the styled component
Group 4: styled
Group 5: View
Group 6: Style Properties

Check out this example
https://regex101.com/r/dCrexb/1

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444230/6320488

Hope this helps. Feel free to add comments.

Comment: That works, thanks for the example and reference! Appreciate it.